# Woocommerce - Adding row to cart table

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, actions

I would like to add an extra row to the Cart Table in Woommerce, but I can't find the right action.

From this file https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/cart/cart.php, I would expect the 'woocommerce_after_cart_contents' action to be the right one (line 149), but it prints the content above the cart table. Am I missing anything?

Here's the code (in `functions.php`):

```
function quality_certificates(){
    echo '<tr>TEST</tr>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_cart_contents','quality_certificates');
```

And this is the output:

```
<form class="woocommerce-cart-form" action="..." method="post">

  TEST<table class="shop_table ...">
```

etc.

Comment: An extra row on the cart page table

Comment: Are you sure it's actually above the cart table? Try inspecting the HTML.

Comment: Yes, it's outside the actual table, right under the opening `<form>` tag.

Comment: I want to add an extra `<tr>` to the table. From the woocommerce file I linked to, it seems like this is possible with `'woocommerce_after_cart_contents'`. But using that hook actually places the code above the table, not inside of it.

Comment: That's strange @Pim. But you can try the `woocommerce_cart_contents` action, though that would add the row above the row which contains the coupon details and submit button, and not before the `</table>`.

Comment: I mean, `</tbody>` as in the default markup.

Comment: @SallyCJ Strange, this also prints above the table. I'll update my question with my exact code.

Comment: It'd also be helpful to include a screenshot of the generated markup, and the visual output. Check also for a plugin which may have caused the strange behavior. And the theme as well, just in case.

Comment: @SallyCJ Just updated, with the output. Theme is WooCommerce's storefront.

Comment: Try `return` instead of `echo`?

Comment: @WebElaine No output at all with `return`. Also, checked the parent theme and nothing weird going on there as far as overriding hooks/templates and such.

Comment: I think the problem is - invalid/improper markup.. try `echo '<tr><td colspan="6">Test</td></tr>';` instead of just `<tr>TEST</tr>`. I tried this, and it worked for me. (Using Storefront) =)

Comment: @SallyCJ You are right, that's the issue! If you wanna write that in an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the right "action", which is `woocommerce_after_cart_contents`.

But when I tried the markup you used:

```
function quality_certificates(){
    echo '<tr>TEST</tr>';
}
```

this was the visual output: *(I actually initially tested with the Twenty Seventeen theme; sorry about that. But this one is tested with Storefront)*

[image]

Then I started thinking that the problem *might* be the markup, so I changed it to:

```
<tr><td colspan="6">TEST</td></tr>
```

and voila! I got the expected visual output:

[image]

So, **use the proper markup/HTML**. =)

*PS: Those are **actual** screenshots. ;-)*

Answer (score 0):

try this below hook

```
function custom_cart_function(){

     echo 'demo';
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_cart_table', 'custom_cart_function');
```

Comment: That one displays after the cart, I would need the hook that displays inside the cart table, at the end of it.